# Anaconda Prompt launches wrong conda installation

Tags: conda, arcgis, anaconda3

I have two conda installations that I need for different projects :

1. Anaconda installation located at : `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3`
2. ArcGIS Pro located at : `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python`

However, when I use the Anaconda Prompt icon (from Anaconda installation), I keep getting the envs from the ArcGIS Pro installation.
The Anaconda Prompt icon use the following command : `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3`.
But if I display the available environments with `conda env list`, I get :

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python
arcgispro-py3            C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
                      *  C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3
```

And if I create a new env (here named `test`), it is created in the ArcGIS folder (ESRI is the name of the company owning ArcGIS):

```
test                     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\test
```

Uninstalling ArcGIS Pro corrects the problem :

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3
test                     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\test
```

However, after reinstalling it, the problem reappeared.

Anyone knows which files need to be modified to keep the ArcGIS Pro conda installation apart from the Anaconda one ?

Comment: Ugh. It really sucks that third parties (ArcGIS) do this. Better engineering would be for them to use a standalone like micromamba and keep all this hidden instead of polluting user-space. Also would help if Conda installers would freak out more prominently when detecting an existing installation in user space - only one is ever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the problem came from, but I managed to overwrite the conda `root_prefix` parameter. So now, the ArcGIS Pro envs do not appear.

In the Anaconda Prompt :
`conda config --set root_prefix C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3`

Verification :
`conda env list` gives :

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3
test                     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\test
```